# Having multiple validation errors in single error message in Peoplesoft

Tags: peoplesoft, peoplecode

Is it possible to get multiple error messages for missing required fields in a single error message to the user? For example, if I left all 5 of my required fields blank, the error message that is displayed when clicking Submit will show all 5 messages in the same window.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fantastic idea and should be added to the PeopleSoft Idea Spaces in MyOracle Support. Unfortunately, this is not delivered. There are multiple ways a person might trigger an exception, including:

- Choosing an invalid value
- Leaving required fields blank
- Failing FieldEdit or SaveEdit PeopleCode

Unfortunately, PeopleSoft fails on the first, not all. Regarding the last item: FieldEdit/SaveEdit, as soon as you trigger the PeopleCode Error function, PeopleCode halts, so it is impossible for us to use the Error function to queue multiple exceptions.

With all that said, nothing is impossible. One way to accomplish this would be to use our own JavaScript/CSS to mark all fields that fail validation. This would require us to write additional PeopleCode, etc., to work around Oracle's delivered validation.

Answer (score 0):

One approach to do that is to perform the validations "manually", stack then and present to the user.
In order to do that, you need to have a custom "Save" or "Validate Button", and your peoplecode would stack the errors.

You can use the vanilla required fields validation + any conditional validation you need.

A good way to present this is just have a field(long) or an html area and nicely present the errors:

- Emplid is required
- Setid is required
- Enter an end date less than start date

But otherwise, this is not part of Peopletools, although some modules do offer this (eSupplier Portal for instance has a similar feature).